# How to Generate API docs for KOA Based server

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa, koa-router

I am having a KOA based server. now i want to generate API docs for the server. Is there any tools for auto generating API Docs

Answer (score 3):

You can use [apiDoc](http://apidocjs.com) or [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org). Both of these libraries create a documentation from your annotations.